# Getting Error on Updating CSV file into SOLR: Expected fieldnames in CSV input

Tags: csv, solr

I wanna Import a csv File using File Path But whene i want to upload this i get msg= Expected fieldnames in CSV input ErrorNumber=400

I am using this url :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Log/update?wt=json&commitWithin=1000&overwrite=true&stream.file=Log\Log.csv&stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

Im using SOLR 4.2 and my file is Store in c:. i am using Windows 8.1

thank you

Comment: You've left too much information out for your question to be solved. Read up on CSV updating at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV, then modify your question with more details. (Hint: you'll likely find your answer in the wiki.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I changed the query URL to something like this and it worked

```
http://localhost:xxxx/solr/update/csv?stream.file=<remote path>/Log.csv&stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

just replace "remote path" with your own path

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this problem often happens when the path of CSV file is invalid.

For example:

```
SOLR_URL="localhost:8983/solr/collection_1"
DATA_FILE=/tmp/file_data.csv
curl "$SOLR_URL/update?commit=true" --data-binary @$DATA_FILE -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

I had to double check the `DATA_FILE` path.